# How to solve problem conflicts with your root composer.json require?

Tags: laravel, paypal

when I want to composer install srmklive/paypal using **composer require srmklive/paypal**, I get the error like belok:

```
 Problem 1
    - srmklive/paypal[v3.0, ..., 3.0.10] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~7.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.0.0, ..., 7.4.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^6.3).
    - Root composer.json requires srmklive/paypal ^3.0 -> satisfiable by srmklive/paypal[v3.0, ..., 3.0.10].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: It is saying that you have manually added `guzzlehttp/guzzle: ^6.3` on your main `composer.json`, is there a reason? Can you upgrade it to `^7.0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change in composer.json

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3|^7.0.1",
```

Then update composer

Answer (score -1):

> We have resolved this issue with the below commands.

```
Update the "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3|^7.0.1",

Or last you can try with all dependencies option

composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle --with-all-dependencies
```

> Thanks